# Can I colorize transparent areas, and make colored areas transparent, in Gimp 2?

Tags: gimp

I created a shape on a transparent background, but I actually want the shape to be transparent and the background to be a solid color.

Can this be done?

I don't want to just Select By Color, because that doesn't select the partially-transparent areas, giving the shape rough edges.

Comment: You basically just need to invert the alpha channel. Sorry, I have no Gimp at hand right now to guide you through this...

Comment: @AAGD Do you have a guess for where that tool can be found?

Answer (score 3):

To invert transparency from background to foreground I usually take the following steps shown with the source example below:

[image]

1. Make the alpha-channel a selection (*Layer > Transparency > Alpha to Selection*)

[image]

2. Invert the selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to select background
3. Fill the background with desired color/pattern
4. Invert the selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> to select foreground
5. Remove the foreground (<kbd>Del</kbd>)

[image]

We can see that semi-transparency for anti-aliasing will be nicely preserved:

[image]